# Firestore Rules - why my teste on lab tests do not pass

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

thanks for any can help.

I hay a doc

```
/rooms/CAhYMQ3aDFvsDxrIxyg
```

and rule

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

 [...]

 match /rooms/{roomId} {
   allow get;
 }

 [...]

}
```

But when test this "route" they dont pass

(test lab)

- type simulation: get
- local: /rooms/CAhYMQ3aDFvsDxrIxyga
- auth: true

**Edit:**

all rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  match /users/{userId}/{anyUserFile=**} {
    allow read: if IsAuth();
  }
  
  match /users/{userId}/{anyUserFile=**} {
    allow write: if IsOwner(userId);
  }
  
  match /rooms/{roomId} {
    allow get;
  }
  
  match /rooms/{roomId}/messages/{messageId}{
    allow write: if IsMessageOwner();
  }
}
```

Functions deleted for just put the things can be broken.

[firestore picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmKUr.png)

[playground picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLzdh.png)

**Edit2: (worked)**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

    function IsAuth(){
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    function IsOwner(userId){
      return IsAuth() && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  
    function IsMessageOwner(){
      return IsAuth() && resource.data.sender_auth.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }

    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /rooms/{roomId} {
        allow read, get, list: if true;
      }
    
      match /users/{userId}/{anyUserFile=**} {
        allow read: if IsAuth();
      }
    
      match /users/{userId}/{anyUserFile=**} {
        allow write: if IsOwner(userId);
      }
    
      match /rooms/{roomId}/messages/{messageId}{
        allow write: if IsMessageOwner();
      }
  } 
}
```

I didn't understand that I needed to always declare the database root.
match /rooms/{roomId} worked :D

Comment: That seems to be working on my side. Can you please share what the rest of the rules `[...]` look like and share a screenshot of rules playground output?

Comment: Information Sent

Answer (score 0):

The current Security Rules Provided are valid, it is most likely a cascading issue. Typically this is a result of a wildcard above the specified location that has a condition defined that conflicts here. Ensure that all wildcards and 'default' behaviors are *below* all other defined paths.

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Matches any document in the 'cities' collection.
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    // Matches any document in the 'cities' collection or subcollections.
    match /cities/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

*note the default is listed after the specified field*

**Update**

Ensure that your Rules are resolving with a condition `if <condition>` as while it may work in the simulator, it is not a 1 for 1 comparison to the final result as its interpretation is simulated.

Comment: I haven't wildcard on /rooms path. I put more informations the question, thanks for helping ^^

Comment: updated, you must include a condition. without a condition, this will fail in the live product - this is the same as `allow read: if null`

Comment: `match /rooms/{roomId} { allow get: if true (or check if auth  !== null); }` did not work

Comment: Could you update the question with the query you are using? typically get is applied to a single document only, meaning if you are using where queries, you should also consider `list` or `read` in general

Comment: `match /rooms/{roomId} { allow get, read, list: if request.auth != null; }`  didn't work, is it something with the rules? I really do not know.  Its not conflict with another rule, I tested with just this rule.

Comment: Ok, Got it! thought I thought using cascading match several times was bad practice, but I have now seen the example of documentation.  match /databases/{database}/documents outside my match is the correct.